# How can I describe a matrix A that satisfies some universal property?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on an assignment and I have difficulties dealing with the very last bit. It would just be nice to give some hints. So the question is following.

Given an alphabet $\Sigma$, a complex vector space is $\mathbb{C}^\Sigma$, I need to describe a set of matrices that 
$$
\{A \in \mathbb{C}^{\Sigma \times \Sigma} : A \text{ is positive semidefinite} \wedge \forall \rho \in \mathbb{C}^{\Sigma \times \Sigma}, \rho \text{ is positive semidefinite} \wedge Tr(\rho) = 1 \wedge Tr(A\rho) \le 1 \}
$$

In short words, positive semideinite matrix $A$ can multiply with any trace-1 positive semidefinite matrix, the product of which is always no larger than 1. How does $A$ look like?

Definitely such matrix exists, for example, $\frac 1 {|\Sigma|}I$ is such matrix, but I'd imagine there are non-diagonal ones, which makes me struggle to conclude a common description for them.

What I've considered so far is following:

1. I tried to deal with it using inequality. So $Tr(A\rho) \le Tr(A)Tr(\rho) = Tr(A)$ and claim $Tr(A) \le 1$, but this is too strict. For example, $I$ is such matrix, but for nontrivial cases its trace is always larger than $1$;
2. I decompose both positive semidefinite matrices, $A = B^\ast B, \rho = \psi \psi^\ast$, then $Tr(A\rho) = Tr((B\psi)^\ast (B\psi)) = \sum_{i,j}|(B\psi)_{ij}|^2$, also $\sum_{i,j}|\psi_{ij}|^2 = 1$. But extending it is out of hand.

Do you have better idea?

---

In fact I noticed that the trace-1 condition is very distracting, I would probably say $\forall B \text{ positive semidefinite}, Tr(AB) \le Tr(B)$ looks more friendly. Am I making any progress by moving to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Yeah, the right step is to drop the trace-1 condition and move to the more general inequality $Tr(AB) \le Tr(B)$. Therefore,

$$
Tr(B) - Tr(AB) \ge 0 \\
Tr((I - A)B) \ge 0
$$

Since $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite, the above formula basically implies $I-A$ needs to be positive semidefinite!

So $A$ can be described as simple as $|I - A| \ge 0$.